# Update view not displaying data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a function-based view that does not load the data that was inputted. The view does not throw any error at all. It just presents the form as a blank one.

**urls.py**

```py
    path('edit/<slug>/', editPost, name='edit'),
```

**views.py**

```py
@login_required
def editPost(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post.author = request.user.username
            post.updated = True
            form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
    return render(request, 'edit_post.html', {'form': form})
```

**template**

```py
<form class="dropdown-item" action="{% url 'edit' slug=post.slug %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                    <input class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" value="Edit">
```

Answer (score 0):

render form in **template**, using `{{ form.as_p }}`

```
<form class="dropdown-item" action="{% url 'edit' slug=post.slug %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- render form here -->
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

or **loop through form fields** as

```
<form class="dropdown-item" action="{% url 'edit' slug=post.slug %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- render form here -->
    {% for field in form %}
      {{ field.label }}
      {{ field }}
      {{ field.error }}
    {% endfor %}
  <input class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Comment: It still gives a blank page. In fact, I already have edit_post.html which I was trying to point to with the URL. I have now even rendered the form in the URL link but still giving blank

Comment: Also isn't the URL redirecting to the form "edit_post.htm"? I'm confused as to why you're rendering the form in the same view with its redirect URL. I was thinking when you click on the URL, it'll take you to the "edit_post.html" which then submits the content to the backend

Comment: Additionally, I'm using CKEDITOR for my text field. Could that be another case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
@login_required
def editPost(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post.author = request.user.username
            post.updated = True
            form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'edit_post.html', {'form': form})
```

Probably you have to do something like that, there is not any reason to pass `request.POST` and `request.FILES` when you don't have POST action in the view. In that way you just have to pass the `post` object that have all the related info.

And also you have to render your form in the following way:

```
<form class="dropdown-item" action="{% url 'edit' slug=post.slug %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- render form here -->
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Notice that `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is mandatory 'cause you are dealing with files in your form elsewhere it won't work properly.

Also checkout where you have to put your `post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)` line, 'cause in thay way you can pass the object to whatever action that is being performing (POST or GET).